# Erlang queue problems

Tags: erlang, queue

I am using the queue api and have encountered to errors which crash my program.

First off I fetch the queue from the dictionary which returns this in a printout

> The fetched queue is  [{[],[]}]

Is this normal? Is the queue created correctly?

Then either when I try add to the queue or get its length I get an error badargs on both.

```
TorrentDownloadQueue = dict:fetch(torrentDownloadQueue, State),
io:format("The fetched queue is  ~p~n", [dict:fetch(torrentDownloadQueue, State)]),
% Add the item to the front of the queue (main torrent upload queue)
TorrentDownloadQueue2 = queue:in_r(Time, TorrentDownloadQueue),
% Get the lenght of the downloadQueue
TorrentDownloadQueueLength = queue:len(TorrentDownloadQueue2),
```

When I try to insert the value 10 the error is

> ** Reason for termination == 
>   ** {badarg,[{queue,in_r,[10,[{[],[]}]]},
>               {ph_speed_calculator,handle_cast,2},
>               {gen_server,handle_msg,5},
>               {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]}
>   ** exception exit: badarg
>        in function  queue:in_r/2
>           called as queue:in_r(10,[{[],[]}])
>        in call from ph_speed_calculator:handle_cast/2
>        in call from gen_server:handle_msg/5
>        in call from proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3
>   13>

This is the error for the in_r, but I get a badargs error for the len call too.

What is wrong with the way I call these or is the inital Queue incorrect?
I create the queue as follows and add it to the dictionary

```
TorrentDownloadQueue = queue:new(),
TorrentUploadQueue = queue:new(),
D4 = dict:store(torrentDownloadQueue, [TorrentDownloadQueue], D3),
D5 = dict:store(torrentUploadQueue, [TorrentUploadQueue], D4),
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have (`[{[],[]}]`) is a queue in a list. A standard queue looks like `{list(), list()}`. Obviously, because of this, every subsequent call to queues will fail.

My guess is that you either carry your queue wrong or extract it in the wrong manner.

Comment: Thanks so much. It now looks clear what I was doing wrong, I thought the Value of a dictionary had to be within [ ]. I dont know why I did. I have checked my code over and over, overlooking this. I cant thank you enough

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you've got is a "badarg" error. Reading from the documentation for Erlang queues:

> All functions fail with reason badarg
>   if arguments are of wrong type, for
>   example queue arguments are not
>   queues, indexes are not integers, list
>   arguments are not lists. Improper
>   lists cause internal crashes. An index
>   out of range for a queue also causes a
>   failure with reason badarg.

In your case, what you pass to the queue:in_r is not a queue, but a list containing a queue.

You're adding a list containing a queue to the dictionary when you do:

```
D4 = dict:store(torrentDownloadQueue, [TorrentDownloadQueue], D3),
D5 = dict:store(torrentUploadQueue, [TorrentUploadQueue], D4),
```

You should do, instead, simply:

```
D4 = dict:store(torrentDownloadQueue, TorrentDownloadQueue, D3),
D5 = dict:store(torrentUploadQueue, TorrentUploadQueue, D4),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help on both questions. So I was passing the state around correctly. I have no idea why I thought the Value had to be [Value]. :)